# Hex 1F as string separator

Tags: asp-classic, hex

How do I split a string (response back from a non-standard Web Service) separated by "" (between quotes, that's how it looks like in a browser or text file)? It is supposed to be a Hex 1F. In my code, if I split by "", it works. I tried FieldSeparator = Hex(1F), 0x1F, nothing works (only "" which makes sense, I'm not looking to convert to decimal). It wouldn't be so bad, but I also need to split by 1E and I haven't been able to find one (to copy and paste and use in my code) yet. And I would also like to understand why 1F ("1" and "15" in hex) look like that... Thanks!!

Comment: Could you describe what kind of data you're parsing? It sounds like marcxml which still contains control characters (which is an error at the sender), or parsing binary data as string content.

Comment: The response from the web service is base64 encoded, looks like this:

Comment: The string I am parsing is actually the xml element "GetHostReply" from the response. It comes in base64 encoded, looks like that after decoding: 50000000000NA00000021600106 01845010184628 LINDON LN                            01847VERNON HILLS IL 60061-2406              01848 01849 02576ND02577007100016894. Please note the separators "" (1f and 1e). There might be a way to have the string as xml, too, but I don't know how, documentation is as good as non-existent, with the exception of field numbers and names (between "", the first 5 chars ar a field number). Thanks!

Comment: just noticed, al the separators are gone from my comment...

Comment: Can you just modify your base64 decode routine to give you an integer-array, and read (and transform to characters) yourself, while handling any 0x1E and 0x1F?

Comment: I guess I could try, I don't know if it would help, because for now, I was able to isolate the other separator and use it in my code... Thanks for your help. I thought it's easier than that...

Comment: If you got your case resolved please either share the solution as new answer (and accept it) or delete this question if you don't think others can benefit from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the chr function, [see here](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_chr.asp) for help to get the character.

```
dim array_var, input_string

array_var = split(input_string, CHR(&H1F))
```

I don't know if you are familiar with the &H.. syntax, this is the VBScript equivalent of the 0x.. syntax in other languages.